# Can I use one NIC team for the host and the VMs? Or do I need a separate NIC and a team for the VMs?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, nic-teaming

I'm a newbie here. I have a Windows 2019 server with two 10G fiber lines. I created a NIC team for the host with LACP / Dynamic mode.

Can I use this team for both the host and Hyper-v VMs? Or do I need a separate physical NIC and lines for VMs?

I encountered an error when I ran this command:

New-VMSwitch -Name External -NetAdapterName "NIC1","NIC2" -EnableEmbeddedTeaming $true

The error shows "A protocol on the network adapter prevented it from binding to the virtual switch".

Please help.

Comment: What happens if you try to create a virtual switch using the team from the Hyper-V GUI management console?

Comment: In Hyper-V GUI management console, I selected "Microsoft Network adapter multiplex Driver", and created it. It went through, but the host network connection became offline. I deleted the virtual switch I had just created, and the host connection returned online. It looks like a NIC team can't be shared with both.

Comment: When you created the virtual switch did you enable the option "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter"?

Comment: As an aside, you can create virtual switches that are shared with the management OS or not shared. It's up to you. If you create a virtual switch that is not shared with the management OS then you need a dedicated NIC for the management OS.

Comment: `-AllowManagementOS` "Specifies whether the parent partition (i.e. the management operating system) is to have access to the physical NIC bound to the virtual switch to be created." When a new switch is created, the Internet protocols are removed from the physical adapters. If those are in use, it may produce unexpected results. Additionally, if you created a "legacy" team, those were deprecated 10 years ago. Switch Embedded Teams are preferred.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/new-vmswitch

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/bypass-lbfo-teaming-deprecation-on-hyper-v-and-windows-server/m-p/3672310

Answer (score 1):

You can - but bandwidth can be a problem. A SET (Switch embedded team) with QoS profiles is a must - as is a not low-end switch (10g++). 2022 upward strongly adviced.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know what the purpose is of NIC Teaming and where it's used for?

NIC Teaming is usually done on the Hyper-v host.
In a VM just add multiple virtual nics. NIC Teaming relies as far as I know on the psychical nic, so I think with a virtual nic you might get very strange and undesired effects.